# jQuery accordion for iPhone only

Tags: jquery

Is there a better way of making an accordion work for iPhone only?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var device = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var ios = device.match(/(iphone|ipod|ipad)/);
if (ios) {
    $("#Main_Box_Section .box2:not(:first)").hide();
    $("#Main_Box_Section h3").click(function () {
        $(this).next(".box2").slideToggle("slow").siblings(".box2:visible").slideUp("slow")
    })
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [Zepto.js](https://github.com/madrobby/zepto/blob/master/src/detect.js#files):

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();

var ipad = ua.match(/(iPad).*OS\s([\d_]+)/);
var iphone = !ipad && ua.match(/(iPhone\sOS)\s([\d_]+)/);

if(iphone){
   ...
}
```